# Switching from PHP !ereg and !eregi to preg_match

Tags: php

I hope someone can help!!!

In coding a form validation, I got the error message `"Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\Zacel_Development\sa_model_watch.co.za\insert_newProf.php on line 184"`

I did some research and found out I need to change !eregi and !ereg to preg_match...

I did try this, but to no avail...  can anyone please check my code and advise as I am stumped!

My Code Snippet:

```
/* Check is numeric*/
$regex = "[0-9]{10}";
   if(!ereg($regex,$field)){
   $form->setError($fieldValue, "* Contact number invalid");
   }
```

SHOULD APPARENTLY BE:

```
/* Check is numeric*/
$regex = "[0-9]{10}";
 if(!preg_match($regex,$field)){
 $form->setError($fieldValue, "* Contact number invalid");
 }
```

AND:

```
/* Check if valid email address */
$regex = "^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
     ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
     ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$";
    if(!eregi($regex,$field)){
      $form->setError($fieldValue, "* Email invalid");
      }
```

SHOULD APPARENTLY BE:

```
/* Check if valid email address */
$regex = "^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
     ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
     ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$";
    if(!preg_match($regex,$field)){
      $form->setError($fieldValue, "* Email invalid");
      }
```

This still doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open and close your regex pattern with a delimiter:

So that:

```
$regex = "[0-9]{10}";
```

becomes

```
$regex = "/[0-9]{10}/";
```

If you want the pattern to be case insensitive use the `i` flag

```
$regex = "/somepattern/i";
```

Comment: Tnx @PeeHaa,  This worked wonders!  YOU ROCK MAN!!!

Comment: @PeeHaa, this may sound so daft, but, I've looked over this entire site and can't find out how to mark the question as answered...lol.. do I just click on "answer your question"?

Comment: @Celeste: You can accept answers by ticking the check mark underneath the votes.

Comment: @PeeHaa:  Thanks so much once again!

Comment: @Celeste: No problem and welcome on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

here you are some example:

over from ereg, preg_match can be quite intimidating. to get started here is a migration tip.

```
<?php
if(ereg('[^0-9A-Za-z]',$test_string)) // will be true if characters arnt 0-9, A-Z or a-z.

if(preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z]/',$test_string)) // this is the preg_match version. the /'s are now required.
?>
```

Comment: Just to avoid confusion when reading other code: The `/` is not explicitly required. You can choose every delimiter you like. The first character of the pattern is always treated as the delimiter, so if you start your pattern e.g. with `~` this one used and is required as ending symbol instead of `/`.