# replace deprecated ereg with what_function()

Tags: php

I have  a code which read file inside a directory.
But I am using `ereg()`, 
Now I am getting a deprecated error on PHP 5.3.

After search on google, someone said to replace `ereg()` with `perg_match()`.

But after replacing with `perg_math()` I am getting an error:

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '.' found

I am not a PHP expert kndly fix this problem.

```
$path = THEME_DIR.'/'.$path;
foreach(array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')) as $f) 
    if (is_file($path . '/' . $f) && (('.php') ? ereg('.php' . '$' , $f) : 1)) 
        $l[] = $f;
return $l;
```

Comment: Did you read the entry for preg_match() on the manual?

Comment: Yes, but did not understand that

Comment: You need to add delimiters to your regex when using `preg_match`. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: _I am not a PHP expert kndly fix this problem._ RTFM

Comment: Try to read this:  [Switching from PHP !ereg and !eregi to preg_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465601/switching-from-php-ereg-and-eregi-to-preg-match) or this [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preg_match regex should be inside the delimeters.. "/your regex here/".. the deprecated POSIX regex were the one which did not require any delimeter.. eg ereg(")

so just change your regex to

```
"/old regex/"
```

[PHP regular expressions: No ending delimiter '^' found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634993/php-regular-expressions-no-ending-delimiter-found-in)
for reference

```
$path = THEME_DIR.'/'.$path;
foreach(array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')) as $f) 
    if (is_file($path . '/' . $f) && (('.php') ? ereg('/.php' . '$/' , $f) : 1)) 
        $l[] = $f;
return $l;
```